# Bittorrent tracker request, format of info_hash

Tags: bittorrent

When I want to send an initial request to a tracker all references I've seen says it needs to be url-encoded. If I transform the SHA-1 hash I have of the info key into a hex string, why would I need to url-encode the hash? It only contains allowed characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `info_hash` parameter is *not* a hex string. It's a pure binary string, so yes, you will have to URL-encode many of the bytes in it. (This tends to make it longer in the end than just using a hex-encoded string, but that's the BitTorrent protocol for you, too late to do anything about it now!)

Comment: So a byte with value `32` should be encoded as `%20` and not `+` right?

Comment: Pure binary, as in 0s and 1s? That's not what's displayed above. What's the actual encoding necessary for an infohash string?

Comment: Binary as in a sequence of bytes. You then have to URL-encode a byte sequence to put one into a query parameter, so you get `info_hash=ABC%20...` rather than as originally suggested `info_hash=41424320`.

Comment: @lud: it's not really well-specified — BEP0003 just assumes everyone knows what GET requests look like and doesn't specify exact encoding standards. You would certainly hope that both `%20` and `+` would be supported, as that behaviour goes back to HTML2/RFC1866 where the form-urlencoded format originated. Personally I haven't investigated what trackers actually support and would tend to plump for `%20` to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Binary form of info-hash (a 20 byte long SHA1) should be URL encoded. AFAIK some trackers accept pure hexadecimal info-hash (40 character long string).