# cant send a tracker announcement request using aiohttp

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp, bittorrent

I try to send a data to a torrent's tracker server using aiohttp in the following way:

```
HEADERS = {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "User-Agent": settings.peer_id,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

PARAMS = {
    "info_hash": torrent.info_hash,
    "peer_id": settings.user_agent + settings.random_id,
    "port": settings.port,
    "uploaded": torrent.uploaded,
    "downloaded": torrent.downloaded,
    "left": torrent.size - torrent.downloaded,
    "compact": 1,
    "numwant": 200,
    "supportcrypto": 1,
    "no_peer_id": 1
}


if ANNOUNCE_TABLE_HTTP[event]:
    PARAMS["event"] = ANNOUNCE_TABLE_HTTP[event]

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as aiohttp_client:
    async with aiohttp_client.get(url= torrent.connection_info.announce_url, headers = HEADERS, data = PARAMS) as resp:
        content = await resp.read()
```

**Please note that info_hash is of type bytes, and the rest of the fields are either int or strings.**

However, for some reason, it doesn't work.

When I try to send the data by including `data = PARAMS`, I get an error that it can't encode integers (such as my port, uploaded, downloaded, etc).
When I try to send by using json (i.e `json = PARAMS`), it doesn't work becuase it cant encode bytes.

I tried everything! Using urlib.parse.urlencode, urlib.parse.quote, I even tried using binascii.hexdigest and b64.encode to make my info_hash recognizable by the tracker but with no luck.

Funny thing is, that when using requests.get, it works with no problem; But here, the server just immediately closes the connection, probably because it doens't understand my info hash.

Do you have any solution? Thank you!

EDIT:
Strangely enough, if I add the following code it works:

```
    HTTP_PARAMS = urllib.parse.urlencode(HTTP_PARAMS)
    HTTP_PARAMS = HTTP_PARAMS.replace("%25", "%")
    URL = torrent.announce_url + f"?{HTTP_PARAMS}"
    # try:
    async with aiohttp_client.get(URL, headers=HTTP_HEADERS,) as resp:
        content = await resp.read()
```

However, it looks really janky and I prefer not to use it.

Comment: A common issue is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072290/1362755
If not that, then maybe debug the network traffic with wireshark and figure out where the differences are.

Comment: As much as you say the second method is janky, it works and is basically what you need to do (though, I'm not sure why you need the %25 replacement).  `requests.get` is doing that work for you with its `_encode_params` helper internally, just with a lot more code to handle different edge cases.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! I decided to look into it using Wireshark in the past and that's how I got to solve the issue in the first place (I just provided a code I wrote years ago, I just wanted to figure out if there's a different, clearer solution). I guess I will have to do with that, but I appreciate your efforts!